# How to make autogenerated Guid as ID primary key in ApiAuthorizationDbContext IdentityDbContext instead of string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

In ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, I have:

`ApplicationUser` model class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
}
```

This is the `ApplicationUserConfiguration`:

```
public class ApplicationUserConfigurations : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ApplicationUser> builder)
    {
        builder.HasIndex(u => u.Email).IsUnique();
        builder.HasIndex(u => u.UserName).IsUnique();
        builder.Ignore(u => u.AccessFailedCount);
        builder.Ignore(u => u.LockoutEnabled);
        builder.Ignore(u => u.TwoFactorEnabled);
        builder.Ignore(u => u.ConcurrencyStamp);
        builder.Ignore(u => u.LockoutEnd);
        builder.Ignore(u => u.EmailConfirmed);
        builder.Ignore(u => u.TwoFactorEnabled);
        builder.Ignore(u => u.AccessFailedCount);
        builder.Ignore(u => u.PhoneNumberConfirmed);
    }
}

public interface IApplicationDbContext
{
    public DbSet<Merchant> merchants { get; set; }

    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

I use `ApiAuthorizationDbContext`. This is the `ApplicationDbContext`:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IApplicationDbContext
{
    private readonly IDateTime _dateTime;
    private readonly ICurrentUserService _currentUserService;
    private readonly IDomainEventService _domainEventService;

    public ApplicationDbContext(
        DbContextOptions options,
        IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions,
        ICurrentUserService currentUserService,
        IDateTime dateTime,
        IDomainEventService domainEventService) : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
    {
        _dateTime = dateTime;
        _domainEventService = domainEventService;
        _currentUserService = currentUserService;
    }

    public DbSet<Merchant> zib_merchants { get; set; }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        foreach (EntityEntry<AuditableEntity> entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<AuditableEntity>())
        {
            switch (entry.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:
                    entry.Entity.CreatedBy = _currentUserService.UserId;
                    entry.Entity.CreatedAt = _dateTime.Now;
                    break;
                case EntityState.Modified:
                    entry.Entity.LastModifiedBy = _currentUserService.UserId;
                    entry.Entity.LastModifiedAt = _dateTime.Now;
                    break;
            }
        }

        var result = await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

        await DispatchEvents();

        return result;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        ConfigureDecimalPrecision(builder);
        builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ApplicationUserConfigurations());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new MerchantConfigurations());
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

    using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

        try
        {
            var context = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

            if (context.Database.IsSqlServer())
            {
                await context.Database.MigrateAsync();
            }

            var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
            var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();

            ApplicationDbContextSeed.SeedData(userManager, roleManager);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var logger = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();

            logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while migrating or seeding the database.");

            throw;
        }
    }

    await host.RunAsync();
}
```

When I ran the migration, I found that each of the Id of `AspNetUsers`, `AspNetRoles` etc are string - `nvarchar(450)`.

How do I make `AspNetUsers`, `AspNetRoles` and `AspNetUserRoles` use autogenerated GUIDs instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you have also "IdentityUser" class. So change Id line to:

```
[Key]
public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

and also add the following line in "ApplicationUserConfigurations.cs" and "ApplicationRolesConfigurations.cs".

```
builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
```